# loop through all rules in blueprint and check json against file, flask

Tags: python, json, unit-testing, python-2.7, flask

I am testing a flask app. I have many approutes that look something like this:

```
@bp.route('/place', methods=['GET'])
def get_json():
  ...
  return json.dumps(some_data)
```

what I want to do is take this blueprint, instantiate it, and check that all methods that just dump json are dumping the json I am expecting within a test case. So far, I have this:

```
from blueprint.my_bp import my_bp

app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(my_bp, url_prefix='/test')
my_bp.data = fake_data

def tests():
  with app.test_client() as c:
    for rule in app.url_map.iter_rules():
      if len(rule.arguments) == 0 and 'GET' in rule.methods:
        resp = c.get(rule.rule)
        log.debug(resp)
        log.debug(resp.data)
```

However, I have one method which looks something like this as it is unimplemented:

```
@bp.route('/')
def show_summary():
  abort(404)
```

this will show up in my tests, as it seems it technically includes 'GET' in the methods.

Given this, is there any way to limit tests to only include ones which return a json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way could be to test if the response returns a JSON. You could try something like:

```
resp = c.get(rule.rule)
try:
    json_data = resp.loads(resp.data) # this line will throw exception if not JSON
    log.debug(resp)
    log.debug(json_data)
except:
    pass
```